# Why spark environment parameters is not consistent with executors?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, emr

I'm running my spark application on EMR. In spark history UI, under the `environment` tab, `spark.executor.instances` equals `1`. However, under the `executors` tab, it shows that there were total `9` executors , including `1` driver.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spark.executor.instances` this is set to the initial number of core nodes plus the number of task nodes in the cluster.

`executors` is the number of tasks that each executor can execute in parallel.

This link will help explain the various meanings and options:

[Submitting User Applications with spark-submit](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/submitting-user-applications-with-spark-submit/)